# Ionic AppFlow deploy destination Apple App Store and Google Play do not appear

Tags: ionic-framework, deployment, continuous-deployment, ionic-appflow

I`m using AppFlow to create a continuous deployment in the dashboard of Ionic and i need add the destination to Apple App Store and Google Play, but they do not appear in my project.

My project:

[image]

What i need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is your plan in the appflow? You need to be on the "SCALE plan
Custom ".

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but now the options have appeared on my console, magically.